# “Enable Wireless” option is disabled in network settings

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 but I'm unable to access Internet wireless.

The output for `rfkill list all` is given below:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

The output for `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: 90:fb:a6:a7:1c:47
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0410000-c0410fff memory:c0400000-c040ffff memory:c3400000-c341ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:26:82:a0:2f:10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:c2400000-c2403fff
```

When I try to active my wifi i can't...
[image]

I also tried with `sudo rfkill unblock all` but it still isn't working

Router: Sitecom
My laptop is a HP-G62.

Comment: From `Hard blocked: yes` it seems that your card is switched off from hardware. Turn it on and try again :)

Comment: Sorry but how can I do?

Comment: Look for a hardware switch and switch it... It might be that it is a "fake" switch, so maybe you have options for that in the BIOS or, if you have a dual boot, was disabled in the other system.

Comment: no, i've not a dual boot. The button to switch off wifi...I don't use it from 5 years and is still usefull. When i press it, it open a windows in the browser (if browser is open)

Answer (score 1):

Your WiFi is disabled in hardware: on Page 2-4 of the [manual of your computer](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02542455.pdf): press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to turn the WiFi on or off.  If that fails, maybe the BIOS setting is set to not use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.  In that case: press <kbd>F12</kbd> all on its own.

**LQ queue reviewers:** That's it!  **:-/**

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Sorry but it's not so simple. My F12 is already switch on, like it has ever been. Anyway is like my FN button doesn't work, I can't switch off the F12, it is always turned on

Comment: try [F12] all on its own without the [Fn] then.

Comment: @Dank13: Any feed-back on the edit of my answer?

Comment: no, fn+ f12 or only f12 is the same. It doesn't work

Comment: Does the built-in light go on and off when you press [this button](http://www.murraytwins.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/20100209-130044_img_5652.JPG)???  Do you see a difference in the output of `rfkill unblock all` after you press the button?

Comment: the light is always light on,

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) before posting the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command to enable your wifi

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

to disable your wifi,

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

If you want to disable or enable your ethernet, change `wlan0` with `eth0`.

Comment: When I try "sudo ifconfig wlan0 up" I have this

wlan0: ERRORE leggendo i flag dell'interfaccia: Nessun device corrisponde

(sorry but I'm an italian user)

Comment: @Dank13 how about reinstall your wifi driver? yours, should be this one `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Yes, I already install it.  If  retry, it say it's already the installed.
Yesterday I passed 3 hours on the italian forum but no one could help me.
If you want I can pass here the link to ubuntu forum